# Calculating circular motion in a tuple array

Tags: python, arrays, physics

I got a project to deliver for school.
The project is about random movement based systems, me and my mate chose to research a double pendulum set(movement is not random but chaotic).
Our research question wants to investigate if the system can get to a state of periodic motion in any point and in how much time will that happen. 
And my question is how can we detect circular motion in an array filled with 2 values pairs from the model.
The array will be filled like this- (theta1, theta2) the 2 angles of the 2 pendulum rods.
The rest of the variables such as the lengths of the pendulum rods or the 2 masses are known so from those angles we can calculate the state of the rest of the system.
Each array element is added based on the time of the movement, the time differences between each array element is 0.05 a second, so the time of each array element can be calculated like n*0.05.

[image: Double Pendulum]

We can easily export the data pairs array from the double pendulum model we developed using EJS and analyze it using a script written in python or something else, just we don't know what is the best way to approach this.
Hope that the explanation was clear, thanks for helping! :)

Comment: Please define circular motion. Are you referring to an exactly recurring motion? I think you cannot prove that with a simulation. Are you curious about if a joint turns around? That depends on the data representation, but feasible.

Comment: Also, theta1 and theta2 is not sufficient information to determine the state of the system. You need at least one of the angular velocities, but its better to have both, so you can calculate the energy distribution more easily

Comment: Does *circular motion* mean that, if the pendulum is released from a certain position, that `m2` swings around `m1` (given gravity and inertance)?

Comment: @TamasHegedus the two angles (along with `l1, l2, m1, m2`) should be sufficient information, if they describe the initial position from which the system is released.

Comment: Compute the curvature, segments of constant curvature correspond to circle segments.

Comment: I would just search for `(theta2[i]-Pi)*(theta2[i+1]-Pi)<0 && abs(theta2[i]-Pi) < Pi/2`, meaning that the second ball flipped over the vertical direction. Can give some false positives though.

Comment: @TamasHegedus Sorry I was not clear, I am referring to a periodic motion, where the movement repeats itself for a short period of time.

Comment: @jbndlr I referred to a periodical motion, sorry I was not clear.

Comment: If `theta1 != theta2` (at initialization) there will hardly be any periodic movement, as a double pendulum has *chaotic motion*.

Answer (score 2):

**EDIT:** OP clarified the question and stated that he is searching for periodical movement, not `m1` or `m2` *flipping over*.

The approach below refers to *flip detection* for one of the two masses at the double pendulum.

### Flip detection

Detecting the point in time (or the simulation time slice) where the pendulum has *flipped over* depends on how you define an actual *flip*. Let the pendulum's center be positiond at `(0, 0)`.

*Please note that this is only a rough thought that can serve as a starting point for more exact calculations for flip detection.*

#### Single pendulum case

A single pendulum can be considered to have flipped over, if the `x` coordinate changes its sign while its `y` coordinate is positive. This is, because we know, that it will continue its movement into the same direction once it crossed the zenith.

#### Double pendulum case

The definition of a *flip* is not as simple for a double pendulum case.

As OP probably knows, a double pendulum has *chaotic motion* and can only be solved numerically. I.e., its trajectory cannot be predicted.

[image: Idealized double pendulum]

*(Image by 100Miezekatzen taken from Wikipedia, licensed under Creative Commons)*

For the case of `m1` flipping over, roughly the same conditions hold as for the single pendulum case. However, after crossing the zenith, `m1` can still be forced to invert its (angular) movement direction by the forces of `m2` under certain conditions. Thus, it is insufficent to only inspect whether the `x` coordinate changes its sign. Instead, we have to inspect a longer sequence of observations (from the simulation period) and make sure that the direction (i.e. `theta1` constantly decreases or increases) remains the same over that period. Depending on the masses and lengths in the setup, we can surely calculate the actual interval for `theta1` where it can still be forced to re-cross the zenith at positive `y`, but it is probably sufficient to search for a sequence in which all of these hold:

- `m1` has covered an angular distance of roughly `pi/2` (a quarter circle) into the same direction
- the `y` coordinate of `m1` is positive over the entire sequence
- the sign of the `x` coordinate of `m1` changes exactly once at the center of the sequence

For the case of `m2` flipping over, we would have to define similar conditions that have to hold during a sequence ought to be found, but always in relation to `m1`. Let me just make a quick guess:

- `m2.y - m1.y` is positive
- `theta2 - theta1` has only increased or decreased for the entire sequence (movement direction is constant relative to `m1`)
- `m2.x - m1.x` changes sign exactly once in this sequence (`m2` crosses zenith over `m1`)
- ... a few more?